# Implementing regularized logistic regression in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I assigned myself a problem that involved creating a method for regularized logistic regression in Pytorch without directly using any methods that incorporate regularization. I wanted to also practice using the Module class in pytorch (although that may have made this artifically difficult). My below approach is throwing a runtime error:

Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

at the line `loss = criterion(y_predicted, y_train)`

Is this saveable or is it really just best to not use the Module class when involving the parameters in the loss function?

```
class RegularizedLogistic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.linear = nn.Linear(num_features,1)

    def forward(self,x):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.linear(x))


def regularized_loss(lambda_, model):
    for name, p in model.named_parameters():
        if name.find('weight')!=-1:
            w=p.data.numpy()[0]
    punishment = (lambda_/w.shape[0])*((w*w).sum())
    return lambda projected, actual : nn.BCELoss(projected, actual)-punishment

model = RegularizedLogistic(num_features)
criterion = regularized_loss(.1, model)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=.01)

y_predicted = model(x_train)
loss = criterion(y_predicted, y_train)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your code so we could try to reproduce the error you are receiving?